# Yeshiva Bochurim and Seforim

Tags: jewish-books, yeshiva-school

I was curious to know, what *seforim* do yeshiva bochurim learn in yeshiva? (i.e. *Kovetz Mefarshim, Shita MiKubetzes* and *Chiddushei HaRan* etc.)

Comment: A lot of Gemara

Comment: Besides Gemara.

Answer (score 3):

I have learnt by Rav Meir Stern-one of the greatest Roshei Yeshiva in America. He was attached to all the Rambams on the sugya. He did discuss many Rans as well.

That's regarding the Rishonim. Achron that he said over often was the Birchas Shmuel.